# libvirtd not suspending guests

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, libvirt

My guests, one windows, one linux, are not being suspended. I'm not sure why.

Here's the output of `systemctl`, which looks wrong, but I've done `systemctl start libvirt-guests && systemctl enable libvirt-guests`

```
libvirt-guests.service                  loaded active exited    Suspend Active Libvirt Guests
libvirtd.service                        loaded active running   Virtualization daemon
```

and possibly some related logs?

```
Oct 05 12:06:27 slave-vi libvirtd[353]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Oct 05 12:06:27 slave-vi libvirtd[353]: internal error: End of file from monitor
Oct 05 12:06:27 slave-vi libvirtd[353]: internal error: End of file from monitor
```

I'm not sure what to look for at this point, or what possibly to try?

Comment: What versions of stuff are you using here? Also can you suspend the guests using `virsh suspend <dom>`?

Comment: community/libvirt 1.1.3-1 [installed]

Comment: yes it appears that manual suspend, resume work correctly

Comment: OK, so it's an issue with just libvirtd directing them to suspend. Can you see the confirmation that the command to suspend is getting through to libvirtd's log?

Comment: I have not seen one, can you verify what specifically and where I should be looking?

Comment: I have mine set to log_level 3. warnings and errors. It's in this file: `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`. Change it to 1 for more info. http://libvirt.org/logging.html. I think the messages show up in `/var/log/libvirt/`.